# Images not loading in Vue Production

Tags: image, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I'm using Vue Cli and in development mode, everything was working perfectly in terms of images being displayed. Once I deployed a production build my images are no longer loading. The images that arent loading are from an API I'm using, all assets directly in a folder load fine otherwise.

```
<div class='Photo'>
  <img :src='post.fields.coverPhoto.fields.file.url' />
</div>
```

post.fields.coverPhoto.fields.file.url is a http link and is recognized as such in development. In production its recognized as a file instead. How can i get around this issue?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No, I figured it out tho. If I add https to make <img :src=‘“https:/“ + post.fields.coverphoto.fields.file.url /> it works perfectly. At first it was reading as a file so I had to make sure it registered as a http url